# Apple Remote Desktop allowing only Screen Sharing over internet

Tags: macos, networking, mac, apple-remote-desktop

I've set up Remote Management on my iMac, and it works fully on LAN. However,

I would like to be able to remotely manage my iMac over the internet. To do this, I've port forwarded the ports needed for remote desktop (5900), and remote management (3283). I've set up a domain on dlinkddns.com that automatically tracks my dynamic IP. Screen sharing over the internet works, but remote management does not. Is there any obvious reason for this?

Below are the two listings of the same iMac, one is over LAN (hostname Alexanders-iMac.local), and the other is over internet (xyz.dlinkddns.com). Notice the difference in "current status", and the lack of version number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Docs for Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/support/remotedesktop/)

Go there and download the setup manual. Make sure that you check off each item.

Comment: Screen Sharing ≠ Remote Management. Screen sharing is the typical VNC ordeal: remote mouse/keyboard teleoperation. Remote management is a way to manage (potentially 10000s) of Macs, allowing you to run batch files, remotely install deploy software, remotely sleep/restart/shutdown, generate usage/statistics reports automatically, etc. Over the internet ScreenSharing works, Remote Management doesn't.

Comment: Ah I see. Apple Remote Desktop(I see it now in your post)? Sorry, in order to make that function, make sure that SSH and (although I'm sure this one is already turned on) Remote Management need to be activated. Are they?

Comment: They are both on